# how to download this pdf link python - 302 status code

Tags: python, pdf, redirect, request, http-status-code-302

I am trying to download pdf file. I use request. Here is the code.

```
url = 'https://unistream.ru/upload/iblock/230/230283e15180d590198137eba4e70644.PDF'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False)  
pdf_url = r.url 

with open('C:\\Users\\piolv\\Desktop\\pdf_folder\\work_file.PDF', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
    print(r.content)
```

It is this link that opens in the browser, but it is not possible to download it. As I found out, the site does a redirect - status code 302 . But in the standard way  `allow_redirects=False` , I can’t get this file to be downloaded. What am I doing wrong? Where is the mistake? Thanks

Comment: for redirected files, use selenium.

Comment: sorry, but I don't really understand how selenium can download files from a site to a computer?

Comment: there are many sites showing how to do this, here is the first (google) example: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/download-file-using-selenium-python